# Python, Curses, Dictionary not updating outside of loop

Tags: python, dictionary, curses

I am having trouble where a dictionary is not updating its contents where some of the contents are defined by a variable in a loop after the dictionary is defined. It reads the initial value of the variable the first run just fine, but after the variable is changed by user input, the data inside the dictionary never reflects this. I am trying to build a menu system with curses that will build and modify a configuration file for another python script. Any help would be grateful. The issue lies with lightHourConfig

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Topmenu and the submenus are based of the example found at this location http://blog.skeltonnetworks.com/2010/03/python-curses-custom-menu/
# The rest of the work was done by Matthew Bennett and he requests you keep these two mentions when you reuse the code :-)
# Basic code refactoring by Andrew Scheller

from time import sleep
import curses, os #curses is the interface for capturing key presses on the menu, os launches the files
screen = curses.initscr() #initializes a new window for capturing key presses
curses.noecho() # Disables automatic echoing of key presses (prevents program from input each key twice)
#curses.cbreak() # Disables line buffering (runs each key as it is pressed rather than waiting for the return key to pressed)
curses.start_color() # Lets you use colors when highlighting selected menu option
screen.keypad(1) # Capture input from keypad

# Change this to use different colors when highlighting
curses.init_pair(1,curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE) # Sets up color pair #1, it does black text with white background
curses.init_pair(2,curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
curses.init_pair(3,curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
h = curses.color_pair(1) #h is the coloring for a highlighted menu option
n = curses.A_NORMAL #n is the coloring for a non highlighted menu option

MENU = "menu"
COMMAND = "command"
INPUT = "input"
EXITMENU = "exitmenu"
######Variables Default if no File######
lightCycleConfigID = 1
lightHourConfig = 21

########Variables Pulled by File########


#####Convert Vars need as strings#######
if lightCycleConfigID == 1:
    lightCycleConfig = "24/0"

menu_data = {
  'title': "GCB Main Menu", 'lightHourMenuSetting': lightHourConfig, 'type': MENU, 'subtitle': "Please select an option...",
  'options':[
        { 'title': "Light Configuration", 'type': MENU, 'subtitle': 'Light Configuration Setup',
        'options': [
          { 'title': "Light Cycle       Current Setting: "+lightCycleConfig, 'type': MENU, 'subtitle': 'Select a Light Cycle...',
          'options': [
            { 'title': "24/0    |   Clones/Veg", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },
            { 'title': "18/6    |   Mid/Late Veg", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },
            { 'title': "16/8    |   Mid/Late Veg", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },
            { 'title': "14/10   |   Flowering", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },
            { 'title': "12/12   |   Flowering", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },
            ]
          },
          { 'title': "Lights ON Time        Current Setting: "+str(lightHourConfig)+":00", 'type': INPUT, 'textdisp': 'Enter the hour for Lights ON start, Local Time 0-23: ', 'id': 1 },
        ]
        },
        { 'title': "Fan Configuration", 'type': MENU, 'subtitle': 'Fan Configuration Setup',
        'options': [
          { 'title': "High Temp Activation", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },
          { 'title': "Exhaust Cycle Time", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },
        ]
        },
        { 'title': "Modules Setup", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },
        { 'title': "API Keys", 'type': MENU, 'subtitle': "Select Service to edit API Key",
        'options': [
          { 'title': "Xively", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },
          { 'title': "Prowl", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },
        ]
        },
        { 'title': "MENU", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },
        { 'title': "ITEM", 'type': COMMAND, 'command': '' },

  ]
}



# This function displays the appropriate menu and returns the option selected
def runmenu(menu, parent):

  # work out what text to display as the last menu option
  if parent is None:
    lastoption = "Exit"
  else:
    lastoption = "Return to %s" % parent['title']

  optioncount = len(menu['options']) # how many options in this menu

  pos=0 #pos is the zero-based index of the hightlighted menu option. Every time runmenu is called, position returns to 0, when runmenu ends the position is returned and tells the program what opt$
  oldpos=None # used to prevent the screen being redrawn every time
  x = None #control for while loop, let's you scroll through options until return key is pressed then returns pos to program

  # Loop until return key is pressed
  while x !=ord('\n'):
    if pos != oldpos:
      oldpos = pos
      screen.border(0)
      screen.addstr(2,2, menu['title'], curses.color_pair(2)) # Title for this menu
      screen.addstr(4,2, menu['subtitle'], curses.A_BOLD) #Subtitle for this menu

      # Display all the menu items, showing the 'pos' item highlighted
      for index in range(optioncount):
        textstyle = n
        if pos==index:
          textstyle = h
        screen.addstr(5+index,4, "%d - %s" % (index+1, menu['options'][index]['title']), textstyle)
      # Now display Exit/Return at bottom of menu
      textstyle = n
      if pos==optioncount:
        textstyle = h
      screen.addstr(5+optioncount,4, "%d - %s" % (optioncount+1, lastoption), textstyle)
      screen.refresh()
      # finished updating screen

    x = screen.getch() # Gets user input

    # What is user input?
    if x >= ord('1') and x <= ord(str(optioncount+1)):
      pos = x - ord('0') - 1 # convert keypress back to a number, then subtract 1 to get index
    elif x == 258: # down arrow
      if pos < optioncount:
        pos += 1
      else: pos = 0
    elif x == 259: # up arrow
      if pos > 0:
        pos += -1
      else: pos = optioncount

  # return index of the selected item
  return pos

# This function calls showmenu and then acts on the selected item
def processmenu(menu, parent=None):
  optioncount = len(menu['options'])
  exitmenu = False
  while not exitmenu: #Loop until the user exits the menu
    getin = runmenu(menu, parent)
    if getin == optioncount:
        exitmenu = True
    elif menu['options'][getin]['type'] == COMMAND:
      #curses.def_prog_mode()    # save curent curses environment
      if menu['options'][getin]['title'] == 'Pianobar':
        os.system('amixer cset numid=3 1') # Sets audio output on the pi to 3.5mm headphone jack
      screen.clear() #clears previous screen
      os.system(menu['options'][getin]['command']) # run the command
      screen.clear() #clears previous screen on key press and updates display based on pos
      curses.reset_prog_mode()   # reset to 'current' curses environment
      curses.curs_set(1)         # reset doesn't do this right
      curses.curs_set(0)
    elif menu['options'][getin]['type'] == MENU:
          screen.clear() #clears previous screen on key press and updates display based on pos
          processmenu(menu['options'][getin], menu) # display the submenu
          screen.clear() #clears previous screen on key press and updates display based on pos
    elif menu['options'][getin]['type'] == INPUT and menu['options'][getin]['id'] == 1:
          screen.clear()
          screen.border(0)
          screen.addstr(4,2, menu['options'][getin]['textdisp'], curses.color_pair(2)) #Subtitle for this menu
          while True:
            lightHourConfig = 0
            try:
                curses.echo()
                lightStart = int(screen.getstr(6, 3))
                curses.noecho()
                if lightStart < 24:
                    lightHourConfig = lightStart
                    #need to insert code to write value to config file
                    break
                else:
                    raise ValueError()
            except ValueError:
                screen.addstr(5,2, "Invalid Input. 0-23 Only!", curses.color_pair(3))
                screen.move(6, 2)
                screen.clrtoeol()
                screen.border(0)
          screen.clear()
    elif menu['options'][getin]['type'] == EXITMENU:
        exitmenu = True

# Main program
processmenu(menu_data)
curses.endwin() #VITAL! This closes out the menu system and returns you to the bash prompt.
os.system('cls')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the dict, it is assigning the number contained in lightHourConfig, not the variable "lightHourConfig", to the key. So it would never change. There are a few ways to make it change:
You can directly update it:

```
menu_data['lightHourConfig'] = 20
```

But you would have to do that for every place that it appears.
Another way would be to initialize lightHourConfig as a dict:

```
lightHourConfig = {"value" : 24}
```

Then somewhere else when you change the value like so:

```
lightHourConfig["value"] = 20
```

it will update everywhere else, because now menu_data would actually be storing a reference to lightHourConfig and not just the literal data in it. Of course, doing this would have other consequences for how the menu data appears.